# A single-layer network sequential data example

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm going through the examples in *Fundamentals of Machine Learning* by Thomas P. Trappenberg. This book doesn't provide the promised actual jupyter notebook files, so I'm learning by copying and reading the example codes.

Here's an introductory example on analyzing sequential data found in Chapter 9. We want a simple network with a single hidden layer to predict the sine wave correctly.

```
# sine sequence

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import models, layers, optimizers, datasets, utils, losses

# sine data with 10 steps/cycle
seq = np.array([np.sin(2*np.pi*i/10) for i in range(10)])
print(seq)

num_seq = 200
x_train = np.array([])
y_train = np.array([])

for i in range(num_seq):
    ran = np.random.randint(10)
    x_train = np.append(x_train, seq[ran])
    y_train = np.append(y_train, seq[np.mod(ran+1, 10)])

x_test = np.array(seq)
y_test = np.array(np.roll(seq, -1))
```

So far, I see that we are picking 200 points from the sine wave of the domain between 0 and 10. x_train contains the 200 values from the sine function, and y_train contains the next value in the sequence that we wish to predict.

The following code is supposed to predict the sine function using the knowledge of the previous two points in the sequence. This is where I find an error when I run the code.

```
# MLP2
inputs = layers.Input(shape = (2, ))
h = layers.Dense(2, activation = 'relu')(inputs)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation = 'tanh')(h)
model = models.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
print(model.summary())
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 1000, batch_size = 100, verbose = 0)

# evaluate
y_pred = model.predict(x_test, batch_size = 10, verbose = 1)
plt.plot(y_test, 'x')
plt.plot(y_pred, 'o')
```

When I run this code, from the line

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 1000, batch_size = 100, verbose = 0)
```

I get that

**ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_11 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)**

I kind of get it because both x_train and y_train have the shape (1, ) as they are understood as vectors. When I was copying the code

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape = (2, ))
```

I blindly thought 'maybe this is how Keras is written to understand the past two entries of the sequence' because this is my first time studying machine learning and I'm not familiar with Keras.

Do you see a mistake in the example code, a structural mistake or a human mistake made by me, perhaps?

(I have a direct follow-up question because the next example introduces RNN, and it starts with a code

```
# RNN
x_train=np.reshape(x_train, (200, 2, 1) )
x_test=np.reshape(x_test, (10, 2, 1) )
```

which doesn't work because the current x_train only has 200 entries, it cannot be converted into the shape (200, 2, 1). I think if someone could answer to my original question, maybe this follow-up question is resolved automatically.)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop seems to be the source of error. You need to ensure that `x_train` has a shape `(num_samples, num_timesteps)`, which in your case, is `(200, 2)`. However, inside the `for` loop, it looks like you are appending to `x_train` only a single value, and that too in the outermost dimension (i.e., in the `num_samples` dimension).

Your `x_train` must be an array of arrays, where each inner array contains two elements, where the first element is randomly chosen and the second element is the one following it in `seq`. The reason is, given two past values `seq[ran]` and `seq[ran + 1]`, you want to predict the next value.

Since you know the shape of the array in advance, a more efficient way would be to initialize the array to empty or zeros, rather than append on every iteration.

```
# Preallocating for efficiency.
x_train = np.zeros((num_seq, 2))
y_train = np.zeros(num_seq)

for i in range(num_seq):
    # Maximum index in seq is 9. 
    # The last seq of length 2 takes indices 7, 8 for the value in x_train and 9 for the value in y_train
    ran = np.random.randint(8)
    x_train[i][0] = seq[ran]
    x_train[i][1] = seq[ran + 1]
    y_train[i] = seq[ran + 2]
```

Now your `x_train` array has shape `(200, 2)`, as required.

Regarding your follow-up question, RNNs in Keras take input of the shape `(num_samples, num_timesteps, num_features)`. If you have a single feature in each timestep, `num_features` is 1. Hence the shape `(200, 2, 1)`.

You can reshape `x_train` to `(200, 2, 1)` using `x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=2)`.

Refer: [np.expand_dims](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought about re-setting `x_train` as you suggested, but then I thought the second entry of each 2-dim array in x_train would be a waste of memory as it'll be just a copy of some other entry in `x_train`. I thought there were some other ways to make Keras understand the past n entries given a sequential data set without the reshaping.

Comment: Since learning RNN is the final goal of this example, and since you already explained what the shape of the input of RNN in Keras should be, may I assume that it's customary to have `(m, n)` shape if I have a finite sequence of length m (single feature) and wish to consider the past n records in RNN?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to edit your input shape size:

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape = (1, ))
```

Then try to run the code, hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. The code runs that way, but does it still implement the main idea that we are considering the past two entries of the sequence in order to make a prediction? Where in the code is this idea implemented?